# How to calculate cross-sectional correlation in kdb/q

Tags: kdb

How can I efficiently calculate correlation across panel data in q?

Let's assume I have a table:

```
([] date:(...);sym:(...);return:(...))
```

One way I can calculate the correlation of returns between every 2 symbols is the brute force way would just be to iterate for every combination of symbols, use the corr function and add it  to a table.  Is there a way to do this without using an 'each' for every symbol combination?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i calculate correlation matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19958393/how-can-i-calculate-correlation-matrix)

Answer (score 1):

There must be other constraints on table: `cor` requires arguments of the same length.

```
q)s:`aapl`ibm`goog  / symbols
q)show t:asc flip`dat`sym`ret!flip(((`date$.z.z)+til 5)cross s),' 15?1000
dat        sym  ret
-------------------
2017.10.11 aapl 709
2017.10.11 goog 369
2017.10.11 ibm  988
2017.10.12 aapl 224
2017.10.12 goog 586
2017.10.12 ibm  192
2017.10.13 aapl 490
2017.10.13 goog 55
2017.10.13 ibm  465
2017.10.14 aapl 51
2017.10.14 goog 4
2017.10.14 ibm  150
2017.10.15 aapl 890
2017.10.15 goog 99
2017.10.15 ibm  558
```

Here we have the table in time order, with a return for each date/symbol pair. Use [`select` with a `by` clause](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/qsql/#select) to get a dictionary with the symbols as keys.

```
q)show d:select ret by sym from t
sym | ret
----| -------------------
aapl| 709 224 490 51  890
goog| 369 586 55  4   99
ibm | 988 192 465 150 558
```

Produce all the symbol pairs:

```
q)show p:raze s{x,/:y except x}\:s
ibm  aapl
ibm  goog
aapl ibm
aapl goog
goog ibm
goog aapl
```

Now use [`cor`](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/stats-aggregates/#cor-correlation) with [*each-left*](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/adverbs/#each-left) to correlate each pair:

```
q)([pr:p]co:p{y[x 0;`ret] cor y[x 1;`ret]}\:d)
pr       | co    
---------| -----------
ibm  aapl| 0.7845974
ibm  goog| 0.1039863
aapl ibm | 0.7845974
aapl goog| -0.05331357
goog ibm | 0.1039863
goog aapl| -0.05331357
```

It’s still a ‘brute force’ solution – it correlates each pair of symbols – but the iteration is in the [Q-SQL](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/qsql/) and the [adverb](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/adverbs/), generally the most efficient way to iterate.

Comment: To get a list of symbol pairs, you can also do `s cross s`.